# Место страдательного причастия  настоящего времени в предложении?

Tags: причастие

Почему предложение *В прошлом году дом построен.* аномально,

а

предложение *Дом построен в прошлом году.*

нет?

Answer (score 4):

Эти предложения  с разным порядком слов применимы в разных контекстах.

**Дом построен в прошлом году.**

Здесь акцент на *время постройки* дома. Это дом, "построенный" в прошлом году. Так можно сказать, например, указав на дом, предлагаемый покупателю.

**В прошлом году дом (был) построен.** (Возможная предыстория: "Много волокиты было при строительстве этого дома; вкладчики даже обращались в прокуратуру. Меры были приняты".)

Здесь акцент на *факт постройки* дома, подчёркнуто отнесённый к прошлому (он был-таки построен), т.е. важно, что в некий момент времени совершилось *действие* построения дома. Это действие требует применить форму прошедшего времени: не просто "построен", а "был построен". В отсутствии этого **"был"** и можно усмотреть аномалию.